# Different android:minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion causing performance problems

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android app, testing it on my Nexus S. If I am running it, using minSdkVersion="7", targetSdkVersion="7" it performs well, but if I set targetSdkVersion (or both variables) to something higher than 13, the app starts to perform very bad.

After my custom views finished to draw, the GUI of the app hangs (no ANR is shown) for about 5 seconds, then it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I would like to develop my app on API 16, but being downwards compatible to API level 7, so I thought of testing it on API 16 as well as API 7. But on level 16 it performs poorly.

IMO this does not make sense, because if my phone uses Android 4.1, apps targeting level 16 should perform better than once targeting 7.

What are the main differences between API 13 and 14 when drawing Views?

I am using some custom views, the SherlockActionbar and ViewPager from the support package.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details on your app?

Comment: I am also getting similar problem, if i use minsdk only means, my app working correctly, but when i use both minsdk and targetsdk means the app UI becomes huge.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

When you switch to `targetSdkVersion=14`, `android:hardwareAccelerated` will default to "true" instead of "false"

This will allow you to target 14 and not suffer from performance issues:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" >
```

Comment: wow solved my problem when playing animated gif file that it did not show the gif without android:hardwareAccelerated="false" attribute

Answer (score 0):

if you set the targeted version higher than your min version, then you are allowed to use commands that the min version does not know. Its meant for things where you know that higher versions have better variants of code, so you would check what version the device runs on and then use code nr1 or code nr2.

You should only use different api versions if you are sure about how to handle it.